# Custom component doesn't show up

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent

When I set size of the component something more than the x and y of the location of the component both of them show up, otherwise, they don't.
Here is my code:

```
public class AdamakPogram{

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     PlayGround playGround = new PlayGround();
     Adamak ad1 = new Adamak();
     Adamak ad2 = new Adamak();
     ad1.setLocation(100,100);
     ad2.setLocation(150, 100);
     ad1.addMouseListener(new FocusListener(ad1));
     ad1.addKeyListener(new ArrowListener(ad1));
     playGround.addPerson(ad1);
     ad2.addMouseListener(new FocusListener(ad2));
     ad2.addKeyListener(new ArrowListener(ad2));
     playGround.addPerson(ad2);
 }  
}
```

My PlayGround class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class PlayGround extends JFrame{

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   private JPanel zone;

public PlayGround() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
    setResizable(false);
    zone = new JPanel();
    zone.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    zone.setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
    setContentPane(zone);
    zone.setLayout(null);
    setVisible(true);
}

public void addPerson(Adamak adamak){
    zone.add(adamak);
    revalidate();
    repaint();
}

public JPanel getZone() {
    return zone;
}

public void setZone(JPanel zone) {
    this.zone = zone;
}

}
```

And my adamak(custom component) class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class Adamak extends JComponent {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics arg0) {
     super.paintComponent(arg0);
     Point point = getLocation();
     arg0.drawRect(point.x-10, point.y-10, 20, 50);//drawing stomach
     arg0.drawLine(point.x+10,point.y, point.x+20, point.y+50);//drawing right hand
     arg0.drawLine(point.x-10, point.y, point.x-20, point.y+50);//drawing left hand
     arg0.drawLine(point.x, point.y-10, point.x, point.y-20);//drawing neck
     arg0.drawLine(point.x-5, point.y+40, point.x-5, point.y+100);//drawing left leg
     arg0.drawLine(point.x+5, point.y+40, point.x+5, point.y+100);//drawing right leg
     arg0.drawOval(point.x-10, point.y-40, 23, 20);//drawing head
     arg0.drawRect(point.x-20, point.y-40, 40, 140);
}

public void moveRight(){
    Point point = getLocation();
    if((point.x+1-20) < 710){
        setLocation(new Point(point.x+1, point.y));
        setBounds(point.x-20,point.y-40,710-40,461-140);
        repaint();
    }
}

public void moveLeft(){
    Point point = getLocation();
    if((point.x-1-20) > 0){
        setLocation(new Point(point.x-1,point.y));
        setBounds(point.x-20,point.y-40,710-40,461-140);
        repaint();
    }
}

public void moveUp(){
    Point point = getLocation();
    if((point.y-1-40) > 0){
        setLocation(new Point(point.x,point.y-1));
        setBounds(point.x-20,point.y-40,710-40,461-140);
        repaint();
    }
}

public void moveDown(){
    Point point = getLocation();
    if((point.y+1-100) < 461){
        setLocation(new Point(point.x,point.y+1));
        setBounds(point.x-20,point.y-40,710-40,461-140);
        repaint();
    }
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use LayoutManager instead

Comment: @StanislavL that would solve my problem?

Comment: @FastSnail I followed Google window builder for eclipse, it set's the JPanel layout to null then it set's bounds of the component. Is that incorrect?

Comment: @Mohsen Yes, that's what they are for

Answer (score 1):

when you add child components to null layout(`absolute positioning`) you should specify the position and dimension of the component exactly.

using `setbounds(x,y,width,height)` method you can do it.

since you are set location for `adamax` component `setSize()` is enough.

example

```
Adamak ad1 = new Adamak();
ad1.setSize(300, 300);
ad1.setLocation(100, 100);
```

or using `setBounds()`

```
Adamak ad1 = new Adamak();
ad1.setBounds(100,100,300,300);
```

**edit**

this is for your comment

yes let me explain using the rectangle you are drawing .

the main problem is this code

```
Point point = getLocation();
```

this return the location of `Adamak`relative to it's parent container in this case

```
ad1.setLocation(100,100);
```

and from the `paintComponent method` you call

```
 Point point = getLocation();
```

now `point.x=100` and `point.y=100`
and you draw the outer box using

```
arg0.drawRect(point.x-20, point.y-40, 40, 140);
```

same as 
     `arg0.drawRect(80, 60, 40, 140);`

but your component width you expect to be 40 and how can this be possible??
it start drawing from x of the component which is 80 but your panel have width of 40 .so you not gonna see anything .at least (80 + 40) width component need to display left right of the rectangle but border lines has some thikness  so you need 120+ width component to show it.

what you want is change this point 
for instance

```
Point point = new Point(20, yyy);
arg0.drawRect(point.x-20, point.y-40, 40, something);
```

and now 40+ width  component is fine .because this is same as
    arg0.drawRect(0, point.y-40, 40, something);
it start drawing from very right corner which is 0 and width is 40 also component have width 40 + .same for y and height

this is output

[image]

**but**

if you want to move your spirit instead moving `jcomponents` which is not efficient use `paintComponent` method to redraw them .this is good example https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J8a_GameIntro-BouncingBalls.html

Comment: but that's it, you set (300,300) as the size of the component, but it's actual size: is 40 as W and 140 as H. like the size I've given to the last drawRect method in adamak class:     arg0.drawRect(point.x-20, point.y-40, 40, 140); , I don't know why we should set the size bigger.?

Comment: Yes, Thanks for your complete answer.